# How to configure nginx with passenger with rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.1, passenger

I have followed this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu

I have installed passenger with nginx on my virtual machine and trying to access the site.

In the root I have specified path as `root /var/rails_apps/public/;` which give me Welcome to Nginx page,

```
server{
                    listen 80;
                    server_name localhost;
                    root /var/rails_apps/public/;
                    passenger_enabled on;

            }
```

As my root page of my site is in the `/var/rails_apps/app/views/home/index.html.erb` 
so I changed the path to `root /var/rails_apps/app/views/home/;`

```
server{
                listen 80;
                server_name localhost;
                root /var/rails_apps/app/views/home/;
                passenger_enabled on;

        }
```

but still for both root I am getting `Welcome to Nginx` page.

My request URL is like this ->  /#{IpAddressOfVirtualMachine}:80/

When I specified different port for listening eg 1027 then it gives me error `Unable to connect`
Please explain how I can get my site running using nginx and passenger, is there any other setting required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am able run my site just did following changes.

```
Install nginx init script

nginx init script by Jason Giedymin helps us to administer web server easily.

$ cd
$ git clone git://github.com/jnstq/rails-nginx-passenger-ubuntu.git
$ sudo mv rails-nginx-passenger-ubuntu/nginx/nginx /etc/init.d/nginx
$ sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/nginx
```

After that `rails g controller pages home`

And point root to public folder `root /var/rails_apps/helloworld/public;`

then access my virtual machine through http `#{IpAddressOfVirtualMachine}:1027/pages/home`

`port 80` was busy so I used different which is `port 1027`

```
And it works !!!
```

you can refer this blog for more information
[`http://ershadk.com/blog/2012/04/05/set-up-rails-3-2-2-with-passenger-rvm-and-ngnix/`](http://ershadk.com/blog/2012/04/05/set-up-rails-3-2-2-with-passenger-rvm-and-ngnix/)

Comment: And what did `/var/rails_apps/helloworld/public` show you - public/index.html page? How about the other dynamic pages - *.html.erb?

Comment: rails application by default have public folder, so need to have index.html, and about other dynamic pages will be in same places means in rails view folder eg. `views/users/dynamic_pages.html.erb.

Comment: It doesn't have to have public/index.html because if it has it'll be displayed instead of "root" page from "routes.rb". How do I get it to show the dynamic pages from app/views in case of nginx?

Comment: then delete that index file, you can keep public folder empty and in routes you may have specified root url. then it will take that root url as your site home page. But `root /var/rails_apps/helloworld/public;` this will remain as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `root` back to `public` folder, and open the `URL` without the port number

Comment: but in my public folder there no file..so does it will work? actually I have installed nginx passenger on virtual machine. And on my local machine trying to access that site, that's why I am accessing site with ip address of virtual machine

Comment: root set to public am still getting Welcome page.

Comment: Did you restart nginx?

Comment: Yes I have restarted the server.

Comment: And I got the page `my_app/public/index.html`. But I want a default page which is usually `home/index` (HomeController, index action) and which is specified in `routes.rb`.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, you can delete the public index file. Then it will hit the controller.

Comment: But for some reason it returns 404, although it works well on my localhost machine with Webrick.

Comment: What does the server log say?

Comment: /opt/nginx/error.log - `App 18402 stderr: 
App 18402 stderr: cache: [GET /home/index] miss`. Whatever address I go, it always says `[GET /any_address] miss` and shows me 404.

Comment: It looks like nginx isn't aware about my Rails app, it only shows public/index.html which is a static page and that's it. How do "make him be aware" of it?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, I think it would be better if you can post another question, and include your nginx config in it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843478/unable-to-get-nginx-to-work-with-a-rails-app-in-production

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the server name in the nginx config to the same IP you are connecting to, and yes keep the root in the public folder, that's how rails work.

```
server_name 123.456.789.000; # replace with your IP
```

Instead of localhost, then restart nginx.

Comment: what does `server_name` stand for? Can I put my public DNS `http://ec2-11-222-123-11.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com/` in there?

Comment: technically, it would be string sent in the http header called `host`, the easy explanation is it's what you're going to type in your browser.

Comment: So it can be anything like "gjkgdgjk" and still work?

Comment: Yes it can be anything. eg. example.com. You can put here the name of you site that you want.

Comment: well the dns server should still need to be able to resolve it, for example if you choose `facebook.com` you won't steal traffic from facebook, because dns servers won't send any facebook traffic to your server

Comment: Can I put my public DNS http://ec2-11-222-123-11.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ in there?