# Unable to get nginx to work with a Rails app in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a Rails application which is working well on my local machine with Webrick. I trying to deploy it to AWS EC2. I've copied the source of my application from bitbucket to `/home/ubuntu` and installed nginx and passenger (and everything else needed like gems, ruby, etc) by this command:

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

Then I did this:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/jnstq/rails-nginx-passenger-ubuntu.git
$ sudo mv rails-nginx-passenger-ubuntu/nginx/nginx /etc/init.d/nginx
$ sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/nginx
```

Nginx itself is working well(!), for instance:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
* Stopping Nginx Server...                                                     [ OK ] 
* Starting Nginx Server...  

                                               [ OK ]
```

It's installed in /opt/nginx, even so I have to use  /etc/init.d/nginx to controll its state. Here's my /opt/nginx/nginx.conf file:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name localhost;
   root /home/ubuntu/my_app/public/;
   passenger_enabled on;
 }
```

However, it doesn't display anything but `public/index.html`. Anything else is not found. If I remove `public/index.html` then it always returns 404.

Of course, it's not what I want. I want it to work as a normal Rails app:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
 get "about" => "home#about"
 get "contacts" => "home#contacts"

 root to: "public#home" # I have PublicController and action called home
end
```

not like a web site with one **static** web page.

```
$ ls /opt/nginx/logs
access.log  error.log  nginx.pid
$ cat error.log

[ 2014-09-15 06:28:30.4247 18366/7f9bb38ab780 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
App 1395 stdout: 
App 1395 stderr: DEPRECATION WARNING: Support for Rails < 3.2.13 will be dropped from Formtastic 3.0. (called from require at /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76)
App 18402 stdout: 
App 18402 stderr: DEPRECATION WARNING: Support for Rails < 3.2.13 will be dropped from Formtastic 3.0. (called from require at /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76)
App 18402 stderr: 
App 18402 stderr: [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
App 18402 stderr: 
[ 2014-09-15 06:28:49.3217 18369/7f3cc4259700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:298 ]: Preloader for /home/ubuntu/my_app started on PID 18402, listening on unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.18365/generation-0/backends/preloader.11znc5q
App 19153 stdout: 
App 18402 stderr: [DEPRECATED] The 'safe' write concern option has been deprecated in favor of 'w'.
App 18402 stderr: 
App 18402 stderr: cache: [GET /456] miss
App 18402 stderr: cache: [GET /public/home] miss
App 18402 stderr: WARN: tilt autoloading 'sass' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'sass' suggested.
App 18402 stderr: 
App 18402 stderr: cache: [GET /] miss
```

and

```
App 1395 stderr: 
App 1395 stderr: cache: [GET /] miss
App 1395 stderr: cache: [GET /home/index] miss
App 1395 stderr: cache: [GET /public/home] miss
App 1395 stderr: cache: [GET /fdsfd] miss
App 1395 stderr: cache: [GET /public] miss
App 1395 stderr: cache: [GET /public/home] miss
App 1395 stderr: cache: [GET /public/hoe] miss
App 1395 stderr: cache: [GET /manager/html] miss
App 1395 stderr: cache: [GET /clientaccesspolicy.xml] miss
App 1395 stderr: cache: [GET /hello.html] miss
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you installed Passenger correctly?

Comment: @RichPeck, how might have I installed it incorrectly? It's a gem in Gemfile.

Comment: Passenger is independent of Rails - you'll be better using the following tutorial: https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04

Comment: Specifically this part: `# Install nginx and passenger
sudo apt-get install nginx-full passenger` :D

Comment: @RichPeck, I used `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module` instead. Nginx  itself is working ok.

Comment: Okay - what kind of error page are you seeing on your site? Nginx or Passenger?

Comment: @RichPeck it displays public/index.html, otherwise - 404 (Rails) from public/404.html

Comment: Oh right, so it's actually running Rails? Hmm have you got a link?

Comment: @RichPeck, It seems like it's working now. Why? I don't know, probably because I've run rake db:migrate. But why hasn't the appropriate error been shown in the logs?

Comment: Hmmm I don't know!!!! Have you checked your Rails log? `/app/log/production.log`?